# Oracle - Flyway DB referential data

Tags: oracle, deployment, flyway

I'm looking into the best way to manage our referential data in an Oracle database.  We keep our referential data in source control and our referential table get updated during our deployment process.

We use Flyway to deploy our changes and we setup a repeatable script per referential table to ensure the data is up to date after each deployment.

In SQL server database, we create a SQL scripts that contains inserts statement into a variable table of the referential data for a given table and than use a MERGE statement to insert/update/delete the actual table. This way we can manage referential data per branch.

SQL Server sample

```
-- temporary table to hold all data
DECLARE @product_type TABLE
(
     [id] varchar(25)
    ,[name] varchar(50) 
)

INSERT @product_type ([id], [name]) VALUES ('1', 'Product 1')
INSERT @product_type ([id], [name]) VALUES ('2', 'Product 2')
INSERT @product_type ([id], [name]) VALUES ('3', 'Product 3')

-- merge changes into table
MERGE   [PRODUCT_TYPE] AS t
USING   @product_type AS s
ON      (t.[id] = s.[id])
WHEN    MATCHED
THEN    UPDATE 
        SET t.[name] = s.[name] 
WHEN    NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
THEN    INSERT  ([id], [name]) 
        VALUES  (s.[id], s.[name]);

--delete removed product type
DELETE [PRODUCT_TYPE] 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM @product_type)
```

Since in Oracle you cannot really create variable table or even short lived temporary table I'm not sure what is the proper way to do something similar other than create a temporary table and then deleting it at the end.

Oracle Sample

```
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE TMP__product_type';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
         RAISE;
      END IF;
END;
/

CREATE TABLE TMP__product_type 
(
  id VARCHAR2(25 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, name VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) 
);


INSERT INTO TMP__product_type VALUES ('1,', 'Product 1');
INSERT INTO TMP__product_type VALUES ('2,', 'Product 2');
INSERT INTO TMP__product_type VALUES ('3,', 'Product 3');

MERGE INTO product_type T
   USING (SELECT id, name FROM TMP__product_type s) S
   ON (T.id = S.id)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET T.name = S.name
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (T.id, T.name)VALUES (S.id, S.name);

DELETE FROM product_type T WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT s.name FROM TMP__product_type s WHERE s.name = t.name);


BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE TMP__product_type';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
         RAISE;
      END IF;
END;
/
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty simple to translate the SQL Server approach into Oracle. Use DUAL to mimic an in-memory table:

```
MERGE INTO product_type T
   USING (select '1' as id, 'Product 1' as name from dual union all
          select '2' as id, 'Product 2' as name from dual union all
          select '3' as id, 'Product 3'as name from dual ) S
   ON (T.id = S.id)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET T.name = S.name
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (T.id, T.name)VALUES (S.id, S.name);
```

This doesn't handle the DELETE. Of course you know your own processes but its seems the best way to handle this would be with explicit deletions:

```
delete from product_type T
where T.id in ('4', '5');
```

Comment: I would prefer a solution where I do not have to track the delete separately as it would get difficult when multiple developers are involved.

Comment: Currently you are tracking deletions implicitly, by omission from the set of records. Not sure why that is easier but like I said, you know your own processes.